# Cannot receive WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE messages

Tags: c++, winapi, clipboard

I am trying to use Clipboard Format Listener for my C++ Console Application. The goal is to monitor every change in the clipboard. I create MessageOnly window, successfully call AddClipboardFormatListener in WM_CREATE, but never get WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE message in WindowProc function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "windows.h"

using namespace std;

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        if (AddClipboardFormatListener(hwnd))
            cout << "    Listener started" << endl;
        else
            cout << "    Start listener failed" << endl;
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        if (RemoveClipboardFormatListener(hwnd))
            cout << "    Listener stopped" << endl;
        else
            cout << "    Stop listener failed" << endl;
        break;

    case WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE:
        // Clipboard content has changed

        cout << "    Clipboard updated" << endl;
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    HWND hWindow = nullptr;

    static const wchar_t* className = L"ClipboardListener";
    WNDCLASSEX wx = {};
    wx.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wx.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wx.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    wx.lpszClassName = className;
    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wx)) {
        cout << "Cannot register class" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        hWindow = CreateWindowEx(
            0,
            className,
            L"ClipboardListener",
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            HWND_MESSAGE,
            NULL, NULL, NULL);
    }

    if (!hWindow)
    {
        cout << "Cannot create window" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        while (true)
        {
            // Peek for a WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE message
            MSG message = { 0 };
            PeekMessage(&message, hWindow, WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE, WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE, PM_REMOVE);
            if (message.message == WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE)
            {
                cout << "Sample window received WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE message" << endl;
            }
        }   
    }

    cin.get();

    DestroyWindow(hWindow);

    return 0;
}
```

**PeekMessage** works well, but I don't want to use loop to receive messages.
If I delete PeekMessage or replace PM_REMOVE with PM_NOREMOVE, nothing changes.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You know how to receive messages. But now you are looking for a way to receive messages, without receiving messages. Clearly, that's not going to happen. Now what's the *real* problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I want to receive messages in WindowProc function, not in PeekMessage

Comment: [DispatchMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-dispatchmessage).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your message loop is wrong.

`CreateWindowEx()` sends a `WM_CREATE` message before exiting, which is why your `WindowProc()` receives that message.

However, `PeekMessage()` does not dispatch messages to windows, which is why your `WindowProc()` does not receive the `WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE` messages. Your message loop needs to call `DispatchMessage()` for that. You should also be using `GetMessage()` instead of `PeekMessage()`, so that the loop makes the calling thread sleep when there are no messages to process.

A standard message loop looks more like this:

```
MSG message;
while (GetMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&message);
    DispatchMessage(&message);
}
```